# Can't install ffmpeg on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: ffmpeg

I formatted my hard drive and installed the same OS, but now I get this error when I try to install ffmpeg with homebrew. I am lost because I don't know anything about coding.
Before formatting, ffmpeg worked perfect and I used it a lot.
Thanks!

```
==> Installing dependencies for ffmpeg: rust, libgit2, cargo-c, rav1e, flac, libsndfile, libsamplerate, rubberband, sdl2, swig, llvm, snappy, speex, srt, giflib, webp, leptonica, tesseract, theora, isl, mpfr, libmpc, zstd, gcc, x264, x265, xvid, docbook, docbook-xsl, boost, source-highlight, asciidoc, gnu-getopt, xmlto, libsodium, zeromq and zimg
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: rust
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.51.0 --release-channel=stable
==> make
==> make install
==> ./install.sh --prefix=/private/tmp/rust-20210602-80085-1k2081j/rustc-1.51.0-
==> cargo install /usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.51.0 --features curl-sys/force-system
  /usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.51.0: 20,186 files, 698.8MB, built in 157 minutes 57 seconds
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: libgit2
==> cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES -DBUILD_CLAR=NO
==> make install
==> make clean
==> cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES -DBUILD_CLAR=NO
==> make
  /usr/local/Cellar/libgit2/1.1.0: 98 files, 3.1MB, built in 1 minute 5 seconds
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: cargo-c
==> cargo install
  /usr/local/Cellar/cargo-c/0.8.1: 10 files, 59.5MB, built in 8 minutes 4 seconds
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: rav1e
==> cargo install
Last 15 lines from /Users/xxxx/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rav1e/01.cargo:
   Compiling nasm-rs v0.2.0
   Compiling thiserror-impl v1.0.24
   Compiling num-derive v0.3.3
   Compiling arg_enum_proc_macro v0.3.1
   Compiling rav1e v0.4.1 (/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1)
   Compiling thiserror v1.0.24
   Compiling v_frame v0.2.1 (/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/v_frame)
   Compiling av-metrics v0.6.2
error: failed to compile `rav1e v0.4.1 (/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target`

Caused by:
  could not compile `rav1e`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name rav1e --edition=2018 src/bin/rav1e.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C lto=thin -C debuginfo=2 --cfg 'feature="asm"' --cfg 'feature="av-metrics"' --cfg 'feature="binaries"' --cfg 'feature="cc"' --cfg 'feature="clap"' --cfg 'feature="console"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="fern"' --cfg 'feature="ivf"' --cfg 'feature="nasm-rs"' --cfg 'feature="regex"' --cfg 'feature="scan_fmt"' --cfg 'feature="signal-hook"' --cfg 'feature="signal_support"' --cfg 'feature="y4m"' -C metadata=654b4d8ac219a999 --out-dir /private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps -C incremental=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/incremental -L dependency=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps --extern arg_enum_proc_macro=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libarg_enum_proc_macro-6a796e1ff32c7a03.dylib --extern arrayvec=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libarrayvec-e197a32ab50f1a8b.rlib --extern av_metrics=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libav_metrics-574f181c235aacb0.rlib --extern bitstream_io=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libbitstream_io-f7902f1e6d20e8f8.rlib --extern cfg_if=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libcfg_if-04286ce4a9f9e0e8.rlib --extern clap=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libclap-1f303d110a2f57b8.rlib --extern console=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libconsole-24d65f350878109e.rlib --extern fern=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libfern-858c7167c7df44c9.rlib --extern itertools=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libitertools-07a2e974c46c9767.rlib --extern ivf=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libivf-3689c271c4e2fb2f.rlib --extern libc=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/liblibc-3da17f2610a3bf8f.rlib --extern log=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/liblog-281755dc3732f6c8.rlib --extern noop_proc_macro=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libnoop_proc_macro-cedb9c171d5c2202.dylib --extern num_derive=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libnum_derive-8f2f709874a0c92c.dylib --extern num_traits=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libnum_traits-26d690a7a0420a67.rlib --extern paste=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libpaste-d93c4c8eabe9c329.dylib --extern rav1e=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/librav1e-77585e77aaa27b59.rlib --extern rayon=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/librayon-0fd4dd5503b72427.rlib --extern rust_hawktracer=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/librust_hawktracer-3635df25ee3f3d7a.rlib --extern scan_fmt=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libscan_fmt-9b41f23e7e8f035b.rlib --extern signal_hook=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libsignal_hook-4a59a48977fcfd55.rlib --extern simd_helpers=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libsimd_helpers-a9dc0d41846f6396.dylib --extern thiserror=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libthiserror-11189b9de90e22ac.rlib --extern v_frame=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/libv_frame-4d00008d7891046d.rlib --extern y4m=/private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/deps/liby4m-a22bf8e037405327.rlib -L /private/tmp/rav1e-20210602-43293-1upcx5j/rav1e-0.4.1/target/release/build/rav1e-a5cd0f9aff44cd3f/out --cfg nasm_x86_64` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.
```

Comment: High Sierra is from four years ago, which is ancient in Mac years. In the Mac industry there's a strong expectation that users keep reasonably up-to-date with OS releases, never getting much more than one year behind. Since most Mac users stay up to date, there's no developer incentive to bother fixing problems that only happen on releases almost no one runs any more. Upgrade to the current macOS (Big Sur 11.4 as of this writing) if you can. Unless your Mac is at least a decade old, it should be able to run something more recent than High Sierra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cant upgrade to Big Sur because I have an iMac mid 2011.

Comment: Yeah, once a Mac gets that old, maintaining it becomes a  job for retrocomputing hobbyists. You certainly got your money's worth out of that old thing. Hopefully over the last decade you saved up enough to afford a shiny new Apple Silicon Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download `ffmpeg` for macOS from [evermeet.cx](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).

Put it in `/usr/local/bin` and you can execute it from any directory.

<sub>Consider [donating](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/#donations) if you find it useful. I'm not affiliated with evermeet, but the owner [says](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/apple-silicon-arm), "over the past 10 years there were about 12 donations - in total less than $250. I never wanted to make money with those binaries, but I almost can't afford the traffic anymore".</sub>

Comment: Oh, you saved me! Thank you!

Comment: For stability I am staying High Sierra until my Macbook explodes, thanks for this. Homebrew used to be good at supporting older versions but no more.

Comment: Can you tell me which of the ffmpeg to install ffmpeg-5.1.2 or ffmpeg-109444-geef763c705 ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Macports [https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html][1]

and then running sudo port install ffmpeg
would help with addressing some dependency issues related to the version of Mac OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).